# SQLite database on PhoneGap

Tags: iphone, sqlite, cordova

I want to implement SQLite database for iPhone using PhoneGap. I know  some basics SQLite database in iPhone native application. But how can I implement SQLite database in PhoneGap?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's important to remember that PhoneGap is *web apps packaged in a browser component*. Everything that applies to mobile WebKit will apply to PhoneGap as well, and the environment in PhoneGap is also very similar to opening an HTML-file in a desktop browser.

You want what's called a 'Web SQL Database'.

http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/

**Edit:** This specification has been marked as **deprecated** since the writing of this answer and it's now an officially Bad Idea™ to depend on it.

In reality, it's based on SQLite in most browsers that support it, but it won't be exactly *the* SQLite implementation. But it's close. In Chrome or Safari, you can go have a look at it's contents with your developer tools, look at the 'Resources' tab -> Databases (you want to test out basic functionality on a desktop browser before trying in PhoneGap).

It will work exactly the same in PhoneGap as in desktop browsers.

Web SQL databases are one implementations of what's more broadly referred to as "local storage". I think that the best introductionary text on that topic can be found in Mark Pilgrim's "Dive into HTML5":

http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Still just as valid for PhoneGap as for desktop browsers.

Answer (score 29):

We ended up using the [PhoneGap SQLite plugin](https://github.com/davibe/Phonegap-SQLitePlugin), here's why:

We started off using a plain old Web SQL Database in our PhoneGap app, but ran into the following limitations:

- Size of database is limited to 5MB (the user can be prompted to allow more, but we didn't want such prompts in our app)
- Pre-populating the database via javascript adds to initial app load time

We initially worked around this issue by copying a pre-populated sqlite3 database to a special directory where it would be picked up by WebKit (e.g. as described [here](http://gauravstomar.blogspot.com/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html))

However, in our latest attempt to submit the app, we were told the app violated [iOS Data Storage Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/), presumably because it was copying the database file to a non-standard location.

So we went with using the [PhoneGap SQLite plugin](https://github.com/davibe/Phonegap-SQLitePlugin) instead: This allowed us to include a large pre-populated sqlite3 database in our app and access it from javascript via the plugin. Unfortunately, the plugin doesn't provide exactly the same javascript interface as the browser, but it's fairly close.

Comment: do you have any links for examples of using this plugin @James I've just been going through the exact same process as you. But now I've read this I think I should also be using this plugin.

Comment: @mao I don't have any example I can post here, but I found it pretty easy to follow the instructions and example in the project Readme at https://github.com/davibe/Phonegap-SQLitePlugin

Comment: sorry to torture you, can I just ask which phonegap version you were using with the plugin. It's not working with 1.2.

Comment: Ah, I'm still on Phonegap version 1.1.0. If you figure out how to get it working with 1.2, put your changes on GitHub for us all :)

Comment: @mao My page has a full implementation of a pre-populated PhoneGap Storage API with Cordova 2.0.0, including HTML, JS, CSS: http://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2012/08/21/prepopulated-database-using-phonegap-storage-api-cordova-2-0-0/

Answer (score 5):

I have used this to implement data base in phonegap using sqlite :

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

function onDeviceReady()
{
    initDB();
    createTables();
}

errorHandler = function (transaction, error) { 
    // returns true to rollback the transaction
    return true;  
} 

// null db data handler
nullDataHandler = function (transaction, results) { } 

function initDB() 
{

    try { 
        if (!window.openDatabase) { 
            alert('not supported'); 
        } else { 
            var shortName = 'WineDatabase'; 
            var version = '1.0'; 
            var displayName = 'PhoneGap Test Database'; 
            var maxSize = 655367; // in bytes 
            mydb = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize); 
        }
    } catch(e) { 
        // Error handling code goes here. 
        if (e == INVALID_STATE_ERR) { 
            // Version number mismatch. 
            alert("Invalid database version."); 
        } else { 
            alert("Unknown error "+e+"."); 
        } 
        return; 
    } 
}



// create tables for the database ************

function createTables() 
{

    try {
        //alert("Create table");
        mydb.transaction(
                         function(transaction) 
                         {
                         var sqlC='CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Wine_Table(id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, key TEXT, color TEXT,date TEXT,heading TEXT,img_Path TEXT,name TEXT,price TEXT,whr TEXT,notes TEXT);';
                         transaction.executeSql(sqlC, [], nullDataHandler, errorHandler); 
                         });

    } catch(e) {
        /// alert(e.message);
        return;
    }
}



//insert into database

function insertIntoDataBase()
{
    //Select Row for checking of duplicate Key.....*********

    try 
    {
        mydb.transaction(
                         function(transaction) {
                         transaction.executeSql('SELECT *FROM Wine_Table',[], InsertValues, errorHandler);
                         });

    }
    catch(e) 
    {
        alert(e.message);
    }

    //...Selection ended..*****************
}


InsertValues=function(transaction, results)
{
    var name=document.getElementById('name').value;
    var imagesrc=$('#changeImageBtn').attr('src');
    var where=document.getElementById('where').value;
    var price=document.getElementById('price').value;
    var datepickervalue=document.getElementById('date1').value;
    var color;



    //Checking Area.....

    var len = results.rows.length;
    var getKey;
    if(len!=0)
    {
            for (var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++) 
            { 
                getKey=results.rows.item(i).key;
                if(getKey==name)
                {
                    matchkey=1;
                    updateKey=results.rows.item(i).id;
//                  alert("update key= "+updateKey);
//                  alert("get key "+getKey);
                }
            }
    }

//... Checking area closed...

//for insert in to database....
    var sqlI = "INSERT INTO Wine_Table(key,color,date,heading,img_Path,name,price,whr,notes) VALUES('"
    + name
    + "','"
    + color
    + "','"
    + datepickervalue
    + "','"
    + name
    + "','"
    + imagesrc
    + "','"
    + name + "','" + price + "','" + where +"','"+notes+"')";


//for updating data base....

    var sqlU='UPDATE Wine_Table SET key="'+name+'",color="'+color+'",date="'+datepickervalue+'",heading="'+name+'",img_Path="'+imagesrc+'",name="'+name+'",price="'+price+'",whr="'+where+'",notes="'+notes+'" WHERE id="'+updateKey+'"';


    if(isEdit==0 && matchkey==0)
    {
//insering........************
        try 
        {
            mydb.transaction(
                             function(transaction) {
                             transaction.executeSql(sqlI, [], nullDataHandler, errorHandler); 
                             });
        } catch(e) 
        {
            /// alert(e.message);
            return;
        }
        alert("inserted successfully");
    }
    else
    {
//updating ........***********
        try 
        {
            mydb.transaction(
                             function(transaction) {
                             transaction.executeSql(sqlU, [], nullDataHandler, errorHandler); 
                             });
        } catch(e) 
        {
            /// alert(e.message);
            return;
        }

        alert("Update successfully");
        matchkey=0;
    }
}



celebsDataHandler=function(transaction, results) 
{
    // Handle the results 
    var name;
    var imageFD;
    var where; 
    var priceFD;
    var dateFD;
    var color;
    var notes; 
    var headingFD;
    var ID;


    var UL;
    var List;
    var link;
    var image;
    var heading;
    var date;
    var price;

    var len = results.rows.length;
    if(len!=0)
    {
    for (var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++) 
    { 

        resultArr[i]=results.rows.item(i);
        ID=results.rows.item(i).id;
        name=results.rows.item(i).key;
        imageFD=results.rows.item(i).img_Path;
        where=results.rows.item(i).whr; 
        priceFD=results.rows.item(i).price;
        datepicker=results.rows.item(i).date;
        color=results.rows.item(i).color;
        notes=results.rows.item(i).notes;
        headingFD=results.rows.item(i).heading;
        dateFD=results.rows.item(i).date;

        UL=document.getElementById("wineList");
        List=document.createElement('li');
        //List.setAttribute('data-icon','alert');
        List.setAttribute('class','listShow');
        if(deleterow==1)
        {
            List.setAttribute('data-icon','minus');
        }

        link=document.createElement('a');

        if(deleterow==0)
        link.setAttribute('href','#NewWine');

        link.setAttribute('class','anchor');

        image=document.createElement('img');
        image.setAttribute('src',imageFD);
        image.setAttribute('class','ui-li-thumb');

        heading=document.createElement('h3');
        heading.innerHTML=headingFD;

        date=document.createElement('p');
        date.innerHTML=dateFD;

        price=document.createElement('p');
        price.innerHTML=priceFD;


        link.appendChild(image);
        link.appendChild(heading);
        heading.appendChild(date);
        link.appendChild(price);
        List.appendChild(link);

        UL.appendChild(List);
        addClickEvent(List,name,ID);

    } 
        $('ul').listview('refresh');
    }
}
```

I hope this will help u a lot It contains create,update,insert, handle results after transaction etc...!

Answer (score 2):

There is an article about it on the phonegap wiki here:
http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494756/Adding-SQL-Database-support-to-your-iPhone-App

Answer (score 2):

> Everything that applies to mobile WebKit will apply to PhoneGap as well, 
>   and the environment in PhoneGap is also very similar to opening an HTML-file 
>   in a desktop browser.

Not strictly true; for example with the iPhone, UIWebView can't create a relatively large websql database, which can be created programmatically in Javascript in mobile/desktop Safari, without making a call to a delegate method that's considered a private API by Apple (and therefore won't be accepted in the app store). It's actually an real issue.