# SQLite on IOS with phonegap

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, cordova

Can I use Sqlite with IOS using phonegap (with no limitations) ?
If you have any articles or papers based on this topic please provide me with them. 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a great answer to your question .... https://stackoverflow.com/a/8395768/919545