# Accessing Android SQLite database in PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova

I have created an [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) database and tables in Android. I want to access the same database table in JavaScript using [PhoneGap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap). I have tried, but it does not return any data from the table. I checked the database table, and it has lots of records.

Why can't Phonegap see the database created using Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading Stack Overflow question *[SQLite database on PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139302)* I would suggest the [SQLite plugin for PhoneGap](https://github.com/davibe/Phonegap-SQLitePlugin).