# PhoneGap Local Storage WebSQL, IndexedDB, html5sql, lawnchair

Tags: sqlite, cordova, web-sql, lawnchair

I am trying to figure out the best way to store data in my cross platform app I am developing using PhoneGap.[The API instructions](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) suggest using WebSQL however this will no longer be supported, and IndexedDB is currently only for Windows / Blackberry.

There are many different questions on here [many of the answers are really old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139302/sqlite-database-on-phonegap?rq=1), but I cannot seem to find the **most popular js library for shipping an app with an existing database?** (I.e. a good helper .js to simplify things).

I looked at HTML5SQL but the documentation is very sparse, lawnchair I am not sure about.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this question will get flagged for being more preference bound, but I will give my 2 cents if it can help.

I have been able to ship an app with an existing database using SQLite with Phonegap/Cordova.  Basically how I did it in Android was using the lite4cordova SQLite plugin:

https://github.com/lite4cordova/Cordova-SQLitePlugin

In the native code on load, I would check the default directory to see if a database with a specific name exists:

```
try {
        File dbFile = getDatabasePath("data.db");
        Log.v("info", "dbfiledir: " + dbFile.getAbsolutePath());
        if (!dbFile.exists()) {
            this.copy("data.db", dbFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And if it does not exist, copy the database file from the assets folder to the default database directory:

```
void copy(String file, String folder) throws IOException {
    File CheckDirectory;
    CheckDirectory = new File(folder);

    String parentPath = CheckDirectory.getParent();

    File filedir = new File(parentPath);
    //File file2 = new File(file);
    //Log.v("info", "filedir: " + file2.getAbsolutePath());
    if (!filedir.exists()) {
        if (!filedir.mkdirs()) {
            return;
        }
    }

    InputStream in = this.getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(file);
    File newfile = new File(folder);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newfile);

    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0)
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

Now when the app loads, it will only copy if the database does not already exist.  I can open the database using simply (Syntax may vary depending on plugin):

```
db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({
    name : "data"                
});
```

I will soon be performing the same logic on the iOS side, but I think it should be similarly straightforward.

That being said, there is a plugin listed on http://plugreg.com that provides a helper library for shipping prepopulated databases with WebSQL:

https://github.com/Smile-SA/cordova-plugin-websqldatabase-initializer

I wanted to use SQLite for my project so I opted for the copy on load method.  Good luck!

Comment: Have to say it's very helpful as I'm also looking for a local db that could be shipped with Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

Latest Update: 
[New Cross Platform Cordova WebSQL plugin by MS Open Tech](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Interoperability/New-Cross-Platform-Cordova-plugin-by-MS-Open-Tech-WebSQL)

`Microsoft Open Technologies is publishing the new open source` [WebSQL plugin](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/cordova-plugin-websql) `for Apache Cordova and PhoneGap. This plugin allows developers to integrate a persistent SQL-based local storage solution in their Cordova apps using the exact same JavaScript code across Android, iOS, Windows Phone and Windows Store.`

Comment: But if you use that, the PhoneGap developer app, or in-browser debugging in IE, won't work. This lengthens the dev cycle.